# Hey Cortana responds to me on all my devices

Tags: windows-10, cortana

Is it possible to change Cortana's name per device. At the moment I have my PC, laptop, and phone responding to "Hey Cortana". It's a mess.

I know I can turn off the feature per device, but I literally use it on each device on a daily basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently ***it is not possible*** (you should email to Microsoft about this), however I did a little bit of research and came up with a method:

On your PC download an application called **voice attack**. Get it to listen out for whatever you want and set it to shortcut <kbd>**WIN**</kbd> + <kbd>**C**</kbd>. Now turn off *Respond to 'Hey Cortana'* in the Cortana settings. Test it out and make sure it works.

Then repeat it with the laptop however change the phrase to something different. Leave the phone to respond to *Hey Cortana* and finished.

*Good Luck*

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunally, you're not able to change her name yet. You only can change the name she uses for you.
Here is a topic about changing cortana's name: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-win_upgrade/can-i-change-cortanas-name/31d183cc-c89f-4162-b44d-f14b63286c30?auth=1

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the answer! Generally you'll want to summarize answers from an external source here, since links have a habit of going bad and making your answer worthless sometime in the future.